# Need help converting XML to CSV

Tags: powershell, xmltocsv

I need to convert the below XML to CSV

```xml
<App>
    <SecurityGroup name="Admin">
        <Member username="John1" displayName="JohnDoe"/>
        <Member username="Jane1" displayName="JoeDoe"/>
    </SecurityGroup>
</App>
```

I tried the below one as well

```sh
$xml.app.childnodes | Select-Object @(
    @{l="name";e={ $_.member.username}},
    @{l="display";e={ $_.member.displayname }},
    @{l="group";e={ $_.name }} 
) | Export-CSV "c:/test.csv"
```

The format looks good but the username field and display name are all coming in the same field instead of individual rows

```text
Security Group    Username           Displayname
Admin             John1 Jane1        JohnDoe JaneDoe
```

I need the below format

| SecurityGroup | Username | Displayname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Admin | John1 | JohnDoe |
| Admin | Jane1 | JoeDoe |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *[calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3)* specified as `Select-Object` arguments, `$_.member` creates an array of of all `Member` elements (due to *[member access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.3)*), which is why your CSV contains multiple property values per field.

What you want to do instead, is descend down to the `Member` elements already in the first member access chain:

```sh
$xml.app.childnodes.member | Select-Object @(
    @{ l='name'; e='username'}
    @{ l='display'; e='displayname'}
    @{ l='group'; e={ $_.ParentNode.name }} 
) | Export-CSV "c:/test.csv"
```

**Output:**

```text
"name","display","group" 
"John1","JohnDoe","Admin"
"Jane1","JoeDoe","Admin"
```

**Notes:**

- When you have direct mapping of input and output properties, you can simplify the code by specifying input property name as a string instead of a scriptblock for the *expression* (*e*) of the calculated property, as I did above.
- You can omit the comma in the array sub-expression `@(…)`, as each array element is located on its own line. You only need a comma, when specifying multiple array elements per line.
- The `$xml.app.childnodes.member` creates an array of all `Member` elements contained in **any** child element under the `App` element. You might want to restrict the enumeration to `SecurityGroup` child elements instead, by writing it out like this:

  ```sh
  $xml.App.SecurityGroup.Member
  ```